# ftplib timeout continuously prevents script from running through

Tags: timeout, ftplib

I have a question, which probably identifies me as beginner in programming, which I am indeed.
I wrote a script, that downloads many netcdf files, each file is about 500 mb in size and there are many hundred files. The script would run for several days if all files were downloaded. The problem is, that the script regularly stops with the error message:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

This is annoying, because I would like to start the script and come back some days later when the task of downloading is done. Like this I would have to check if the script is still running at least every hour.

I found in the manual, that the timeout of the ftp-connection can be set manually.
I set it really high

```
ftp = FTP("rancmems.mercator-ocean.fr", timeout=10000)
```

My question is is this the line, where the problem comes from and is there any chance to solve the problem?

Thank you for helping :-)